# Can the Internet use electric wires to transfer bits?

Tags: internet, ethernet, power, transfer

I think it would be easier if the information can be sent from a power socket. So the computer will have 2 cables connected to a socket: the energy supply and the internet.

1-----2-----3

1. AC socket
2. some AC to ethernet converter
3. normal ethernet input

This way the web can be accessed from anywhere where is electricity.

Is this technically possible?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. http://www.networkworld.com/newsletters/lans/2006/1030lan2.html http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/networking/?p=2704

Comment: http://www.fiftythree.org/etherkiller/ - probably not gonna give the desired result though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's called Power Line Communications (PLC) and works reasonably well. There are several brands selling it.

AFAIK there is no built in option, so it still remains an external device.

Note that over long distances, transporting data over a power circuit acts as a powerful RF-noise generator and is considered a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for mentioning why this just dosent scale up.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [**HomePlug**](http://www.homeplug.org/home/) Powerline Alliance website. There are quite a few products on the market, the ones I have work very well. Also have a look [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication) for more information.